# Where exactly does Membership.CreateUser Method add the new user to?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

So I created my first ASP.NET MVC 3 internet application which comes with the built in functionality of registering/logging in.
I tried to explore where exactly is the database the application interacts with.In the corresponding controller/action method I see a call to `Membership.CreateUser` with these parameters.To which [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152012.aspx) says it adds these values to the data store.My question is to which table of what database it adds these values?(so that I can see the updates)

Answer (score 1):

Using default setting, your data is saved in in its default database ASPNETDB.MDF. Click Show all files in the Solution explorer then click App_Data. You should see ASPNETDB.MDF. Double click it then a database will appear to you in the Server Expolorer. On the ASPNETDB.MDF click Tables and find aspnet_Users.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't change anything, go to web.config and find `DefaultConnectionString`. Thats where the data inserted and the table name is `UserProfiles`.

it creates a db file in `App_Data` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but I dont see DefaultConnectionString in web.config

Comment: I'm sorry. `DefaultConnection`. In the root (outer) web.config into the  `<connectionStrings>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the above is true (haven't change the default setup, connection string etc.) then look for tables called aspnet_users, aspnet_membership and a few others prefixed with aspnet_ . that's where to look.

Comment: Assuming you've set up the connection in the web.config, if you haven't then it shouldn't work. You need to set up membership, with a connection string in your web.config. Once you do then the members are created in that DB. If you're not getting an error when creating a user and you don't have a connection string in place then I'm pretty sure they're not actually being created.

Answer (score 0):

If you use default settings then the Database Name where the Table will be installed is: aspnetdb.  Also the table names are self explanatory as seen in below image. e.g. for MemberShip the table used is: dbo.aspnet_Membership.

[image]

The tool used to install these tables is aspnet_regsql.exe, and you can easily call it from 
within a Visual Studio Command Prompt window